# use of pure virtual function defined outside the class in C++?

Tags: c++

I read on internet that very rarely we will define the function even though it is defined as pure virtual inside the class as below.

```
class abc
{
    public:
        virtual void func() = 0;
}

void abc::func()
{
    cout << "in abc::func()";
}
```

I didn't understand the uses of this.  On the link http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/031.htm, it got mentioned that we can use this as pure virtual destructor. But I haven't clearly understand. Can any one please let me know what are the uses.

Comment: The answer is in the link: it is useful if you want to prevent others from instantiating your class. Personally, I think that there are better ways to do this (for example, declaring the constructor as `private`).

Comment: @barak manos: Indeed, though a simple "#define private public" would break that

Comment: @StealthyHunter7 yeah and that "simpel" line would break your standart compliance (and very likely your entiry project

Comment: @StealthyHunter7: Haha, you could probably post that as a separate question here... Something like "why (on earth) would somebody want to `#define private public`?", or "what could `#define private public` be possibly good for?" (the answer would probably be "nothing!" + a couple of down-votes for your question).

Comment: @barak manos: There has actually been a case where someone used it as they were doing project and the team building the API didn't finish yet, so instead of using the interfaces they used private members directly.

Comment: And yeah, @Paranaix it did break the project eventually :P I just wanted to point it out, since it turns out that there are people doing that

Comment: @barak manos I never said it's good...

Comment: Actually link you provided explains it pretty clear, you should mention what in particular you did not understand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A destructor needs an implementation even if it's pure virtual, because destructors are called automatically and non-virtually (up each base class chain).

Thus if you have a pure virtual destructor you'd better also define it.

Otherwise you will not be able to destroy any object of that class or class derived from that class: a destructor call will be attempted in a destruction, and the linker will complain that it can't find a definition.

By a quirk of syntax that's never been fixed, the definition can't be provided inline in the class definition, but has to be provided separately.

Comment: "Thus if you have a pure virtual destructor" doesn't quite answer the question of **why** would you have a pure virtual destructor to begin with...

Comment: @barakmanos: the usual pat phrase is when you want to make a class abstract and don't have any other good choice. but that just pushes the question one step to one side. for why on earth would one want that. i dimly remember that i once knew of some examples. i can't recall them now, so it's not something you need every day, or even every week, month or year.

Comment: I understand (and agree), but I think that OP is asking **why** (as in "why is it needed").

Comment: I'm looking at it, and still can't find an answer: "A destructor needs an implementation even if it's pure virtual" - OK, but why is it pure virtual to begin with? "Thus if you have a pure virtual destructor you'd better also define it" - So why should I have a pure virtual destructor then?

Comment: to make the class abstract. hm, deja vu. ok, "abstract" here means non-instantiable, except as a base class.

Answer (score 2):

Another use of implemented pure virtual functions is to force subclasses to explicitly ask for the default behaviour. A good example is given in Effective C++ Item 34 (paraphrasing (paracoding?)):

```
class Airplane
{
public:
    virtual void fly() = 0;
};

Airplane::fly()
{
    //A default implementation
}

class ModelA : public Airplane
{
public:
    virtual void fly() { Airplane::fly(); } //explicitly use the default
};

class ModelB : public Airplane
{
public:
    virtual void fly() { Airplane::fly(); } //explicitly use the default
};

class ModelC : public Airplane
{
public:
    virtual void fly() { //different implementation }
};
```

The idea of this is to make it difficult for clients to accidentally inherit default behaviour that they might not want if they thought about it. In more general terms, this idiom is good for avoiding code duplication by factoring out implementations of virtual methods which are not intrinsically default.

Comment: I don't think this is good practice because it allows *client code* to call the default handling, which may not be appropriate for a derived class instance. Instead make the default a protected function, separate.

Comment: @Alf, good point, and probably how I would implement it in practice. I think there would be cases in which this behaviour would be acceptable, but can't think of one which couldn't be implemented in a clearer fashion off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

There is no rule which prevents you to define pure virtual methods. This can be used to force child classes to provide an implementation, but at the same time gives you the opportunity to provide a convinient implementation as well (doing common tasks).

E.g If `xyz` derives from `abc` it can uses `abc`s function definition in its own:

```
struct xyz : public abc
{
    virtual void func() override
    {
        abc::func(); // explicitely calling the implementation provided by abc
    }
}
```